# CRM 2013 Importing Action Failure : sdkmessage With Id = [GUID] Does Not Exist

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to import a managed solution that is using Actions.

The import is failing when trying to create the SDK-message. The message is; 
**sdkmessage With Id = [GUID] Does Not Exist**

I've tried re-creating everything but still get the same problem, has anyone had any success doing this?

More details on our problem:

We have exported a solution that contains an "action" workflow and plugin with SdkMessageProcessingStep registered on that action
When importing this solution to another environment, we recieve an error "sdkmessage with Id =  Does Not Exist"
The GUID corresponds to SdkMessageId that the SdkMessageProcessingStep is referencing to in customizations.xml.

Comment: Search solution XML and find any references to this ID.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response.. We managed to find a work around for the issue by retrieving the correct Id from the Action and changing the XML reference in the solution
We need to import the solutions separately so that the actions are in place before we import the SDK steps which is not ideal but works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this issue is not resolved yet. You can vote on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/810477/crm-2013-solution-import-fails-when-plugins-attached-to-custom-action-processes-sdkmessage-are-included-in-solution).

Comment: According to Connect, this should be fixed with UR 2. I've tested but I'm getting the same result when importing. Anyone got it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have this problem after installing rollup update 1 for SP1. When I installed RU1 and try to import solutions, I got the same error. This can be resolved by updating the organization. Goto deployment manager and select the organization and click Update. This will update the guid's and then the solution imports successfully.